# Register xml namespace for msbuild

Tags: msbuild, ilog

I have an ILOG "rulep" project file.  It starts off like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Project Guid="1bd9d4b2-1b37-4950-a4f5-f025bda41c07" xmlns="http://www.ilog.com/rules/visual_studio/7.0">
  <Properties AssemblyName="BusinessRules1" RulesetNamespace="" DefaultPackage="BusinessRules1" RulesetName="BusinessRules1" OutputType="ClassLibrary" PreBuildEvent="" PostBuildEvent="" RunPostBuildEvent="OnBuildSuccessful" AssemblyInfoTitle="" AssemblyInfoDescription="" AssemblyInfoConfiguration="" AssemblyInfoCompany="" AssemblyInfoProduct="" AssemblyInfoCopyright="" AssemblyInfoTrademark="" AssemblyInfoCulture="" AssemblyInfoVersion="1.0.*" AssemblyInfoDelaySign="False" AssemblyInfoKeyFile="" AssemblyInfoKeyName="">
    <Build>
```

In particular, note: xmlns="http://www.ilog.com/rules/visual_studio/7.0".  Also note: not msbuild 2003 format.

When I build the project file with msbuild, I get

```
error MSB4041: The default XML namespace of the project must be the
 MSBuild XML namespace. If the project is authored in the MSBuild 2003
 format, please add xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
 to the <Project> element. If the project has been authored in the old 1.0 or
 1.2 format, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 format.
```

Is there some way that I can register this xmlns with msbuild?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. MSBuild and ILog are two completely different formats. MSBuild only understands its own file format (and can convert .sln file automatically).

If you can load .rulep file into Visual Studion, chances are you can build it using Visual Studio command `devenv /build <project_name>`.